# appending url with $location.search() and setting true ng-show expression not working simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

As I have an input field for search having `ng-model as 'search'`. for this input i update url with `$location.search({search:$scope.search})`. after updating url i set `expression under ng-show` to `true`. 
this thing are not working simultaneously.

js

```js
app.controller('searchCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $cookies, $localStorage, $filter, $routeParams, $location, $window, $route) {
    console.log("in search ctrl");

    $scope.srchfn = function () {
        console.log("in srchfn")
        console.log("localStorage.getItem('user_name') " + localStorage.getItem('user_name'));
        var srchdata = {
            user_name: localStorage.getItem('user_name'),
            token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
        };
        srchdata.search_trans = $scope.search;
        $http.post('http://...../search_trans', srchdata).
        success(function (data, status, header, config) {
            console.log("data: %j", data);
            if (data.success == 1) {


                console.log("search success");
                console.log("data.trans.tranid " + data.trans.tranid);
                $scope.tranid = data.trans.tranid;
                $scope.dateTime = data.trans.dateTime;
                $scope.refid = data.trans.refid;
                $scope.amount = data.trans.amount;
                $scope.status = data.trans.status;

                $scope.type = data.trans.type;
                $scope.creditVpa = data.trans.creditVpa;
                $scope.remarks = data.trans.remarks;
                $scope.debitVpa = data.trans.debitVpa;
                $scope.debitAccount = data.trans.debitAccount;

                // I am asking about these next two lines 
                $scope.showuser = true;
                $location.search({ search: srchdata.search_trans });



            }
            else if (data.success == -1) {
                console.log("transactions not found");
            }
            else {
                console.log("there is some error");
            }
        }).
        error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            console.log("data: %j", data);
        });
    };
});
```

html

```html
<div class="row">
    <div style="margin-left: 24px;" ng-hide="hidesearch1" ng-controller='searchCtrl'>
        <h3 style="padding-left: 15px;">Dashboard</h3>
        <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="srchfn()">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="search" style="border-radius: 0;" class="form-control sbsz searchcls" placeholder="Search" ng-enter="srchfn()">
                            <button type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>



        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="max-width: 1100px; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 15px;" ng-show="showuser" id="searchTblId">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-click="sort('id')">
                        Id
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='id'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('date')">
                        Date
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" type="date" ng-show="sortKey=='date'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('crn')">
                        CRN
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='crn'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('amount')">
                        Amount
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='amount'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('status')">
                        Status
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='status'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">

                    <td>{{tranid}}</td>
                    <td><span style="font-weight:600;">{{dateTime | date :  "dd.MM.y"}}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>{{dateTime | date :  "h:mm a"}}</td>
                    <td>{{refid}}</td>
                    <td class="dsbld">{{amount | currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
                    <!--<td>{{user.status}}</td>-->
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ng-class="{
      'rcolr': status === 'F',
      'ocolr': status === 'P',
      'gcolr': status === 'C'}">


                        {{status}}

                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr ng-if="isOpen">
                    <td colspan="6">

                        <!-- <h3>user details are as:</h3> -->


                        <div class="u_detail01">
                            <div class="item l">
                                <strong>Mobile No:</strong>{{mobile_no}}<br>
                                <strong>Type:</strong> {{type}}<br>
                                <strong>credit vpa:</strong> {{creditVpa}}<br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item r">
                                <strong>Debit vpa:</strong> {{debitVpa}}<br>
                                <strong>Debit Account:</strong> {{debitAccount}}<br>
                                <strong>Remarks:</strong> {{remarks}}
                                <!-- <button ng-click="opnfn()">Note</button> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div ng-if="noteClicked" style="align-self:center;">
                          <textarea  cols="20" rows="5" placeholder="Notes" autofocus="true" style="width: 400px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-top: 20px; padding: 15px 10px; outline: none;"></textarea><br/>
                          <button ng-click="savefn()">Save</button>
                          <label id="sent to server"></label>
                        </div> -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: @Sébastien i have given my code

Comment: @Sébastien see my code please

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly. What exactly is the desired outcome, and what actually happens?

Comment: @Sébastien in `js` I added  a comment line to which I was concerning. My problem is when I go for search, i wish to update url with my search input which is happening as exact but the content which i want to show with ng-show is not showing out. after updating url when i go for search again then only i am able to show the content.